# I want to get space for status automatically when I will click on update button

Tags: javascript, html

By using following code I have to create space manually to show status on web-page but I want it automatically when I click on update button it should create space at back-end by javascript and it should directly show the status one below another on web-page, so how should I get this?
How can I give the cycle for contents of my div elements and how should I show number of status one below another in javascript?

for button:-

```
<button id='statbtn' type="submit" onclick="update()">Update</button>
```

I am using this code to display

```
function update() {
        var x,y;
        x=document.getElementById("stat");
        y=x.elements["status"].value;
        document.getElementById("box1").innerHTML=y+ "<br>";
        document.getElementById("status").value = "";
    }
```

I have to create manually every time and it overrides each time when I will update it I want seperate box1 each time when I will update.

```
<div id="box1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to my question is as below,
as in above code the "box1" is already styled (not provided in above code sorry for that) in css so it displaying also if we are not going to update any text/status so for that we have to call that styled div element in js function and make change in html as follows...

I provided style to "box1" as

```
#box1{
padding: 10px;
height: auto;
width: 650px;
margin-left: 7px;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
background-color:#ffffff;}
```

so it displays on page also if we are not updating any text,

add following code in html

```
<div id="bigbox">
   </div>
```

now make change in above update() function as follows

```
document.getElementById("bigbox").innerHTML += "<div id='box1'>"+ y + "</div>";
```

now it will work correctly,
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the entire content of the `box1 div` every time because you are using `=` operator. Every time you'll run `update()` with the button click, the whole div's text will be created again with the latest status, and you'll get only it's text in the div (together with a single line break).

Change your operator to `+=` and you'll get the previous statuses text + the last status text + a single line break for the next one.

```
document.getElementById("box1").innerHTML += "New Text"+ "<br>";
```

[See here working example](http://codepen.io/Alon_A/pen/vydQgG?editors=1111)

Comment: Wow great..! thank you so much for help, now its working, but i also needed that new updated status should be displayed on new box1 everytime below one another how can i solve this problem?

Comment: @mayureshpatil Instead of the `"New Text"` which I hard coded to be used as example, just use your status text from where it is created from. See the example in my answer, I've updated it to include a random string which is created before the status update. Instead of creating it randomly, get it from your source (its another subject already). In-addition, if my answer helped you, please consider accepting it by pressing the little 'V' symbol near the answer and/or +1 it by pressing the up arrow, for my answer and future answers for your questions, thanks.

Comment: yes sir i understand it but i needed that new status should print on new 'box1' by this code its printed in the same 'box1', i cant get how to print that new text/status on new 'box1'